# Show existence of a continuous $k$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(u,\phi)= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}k\phi dx$ for all $\phi$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

(b). Let $u$ be a distribution on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Assume there exists a continuous function $h$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(u,\Delta \phi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}h\phi dx $ for all $\phi\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. ( $\Delta = \partial_x^2+\partial_y^2$)

Show there exists a continuous function $k$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(u,\phi)= \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}k\phi dx$ for all $\phi$.

In (a) Ive shown $H_{\text{loc}}^2(\mathbb{R}^2) \subset C^0(\mathbb{R}^2)$ which will probably be of relevant importance. ($H_{\text{loc}}^2$ is the set of distributions $u\in D'$ such that $\phi u\in H^2$ for all $\phi$).

So how to show (b)? Tips or suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\in D'(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be the fundamental solution of the Laplace equation (in fact: $f(x) = C \ln ||x||$), so $\Delta f = \delta$. Let $h_n$ be a function equal to $h$ on $B_n$, the ball of radius $n$,  and $0$ outside the $B_{n+1}$. Then $f_n := f\ast h_n$ is a continuous function and $\Delta f_n = h_n$.

So $u-f_n$ is a harmonic distribution on $B_n$, hence by the well-known result of [H. Weyl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_lemma_%28Laplace_equation%29) in fact a harmonic $C^\infty$-function. Restricted to $B_n$, as $f_n\in C^0(B_n)$, this implies $u\in C^0(B_n)$.

As continuity is a pure local property, u equals a continuous function everywhere.

Comment: Hey Vobo. Thanks for your suggestion. However isnt this also assuming that $h(x,y)$ is integrable? And why does $\Delta H= h$ hold true? (or do u define $H$ as a distribution..?)

Comment: @DinkyDoe You are right, $\Delta H = h$ is nonsense. But I think, the key argument with Weyl's lemma can be saved. Probably I need to write a new answer.

Comment: Well I was thinking. Im hoping to make some function H (depending on h) and so that we can easily show $\phi H\in H^2 $( that is showing that derivatives upto order 2  are integrable,i.e. $H\in H_{\text{loc}}^2 \subset C^0$). At least then we make some use of (a), cause i think its relevant.

Comment: @DinkyDoe I have modified the argument as announced, what do you think of this one?

Comment: Ok but couldnt we have argued quicker: Say that $\Delta (u-f \ast h) = 0 $ Conclude from this that $(u-f\ast h) \in H^2_{\text{loc}}\subset C^0$. (ignoring Weyl). However I dont see how you can just argue that $f\ast h$ (or maybe your restricted $f_n$) is continuous.

Comment: Is it because $\Delta (f\ast h) = h \in C^0$ ?...

Comment: @DinkyDoe Sure, this is why $u-f_n$ is harmonic.

Comment: Ok, thanks. However from the formulation of the problem we are not supposed to conclude $u$ is continuous, but $u=k$ (in distribution sense) for a continuous $k$. Also, the $u$ in weyl's formulation, there it concludes $u$ is $C^{\infty}$ after a possible re-definition of a set of measure 0. So shouldnt the conclusion be $u$ is continuous almost everywere...

Comment: @DinkyDoe Definitely $u=k$ for a continuous $k$ in the distributional sense. $u$ continuous a.e. doesn't help at all, as for example the $\delta$-distribution equals a.e. a continuous function too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer for a related, but simpler question. Instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$ I look at $\mathbb{R}$, and instead of $\Delta = \partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2$, I take the differentiation operator $\frac{d}{dx}$.

You then have $(u,\phi) =  (u,\Delta\Phi) = \int h\Phi$ where $\Phi(x) = \int_0^x \phi(t) \,dt$. Changing the order of integration yields \begin{align}
    (u,\phi)
 &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x)\Phi(x) dx
  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x) \int_{-\infty}^x \phi(t) \,dt\,dx
  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_t^\infty h(x)\phi(t)\,dx\,dt \\
 &= \int (1-H)\phi \quad\text{where}\quad H(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x h(t)\,dt \text{.}
\end{align}

It should be possible to do basically the same thing for your differential operator, and for $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$, I think.

Comment: As $h$ is only assumed to be continuous, it is not necessarily integrable. Obviously, due to the compact support of $\phi$, the integrals are finite, but the integration interval depends on $\phi$. So you cannot define $H(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x h(t) dt$ as you did for all $\phi$.

Comment: @Vobo True. But I think that can be fixed by setting $H(x):=-\int_0^x h(t) \,dt$ and using integration by parts instead of changing the order. Will update

Comment: @Vobo Hm, or not. $\Phi$ won't in general have compact support, that kinda of complicates that integration by parts.. :-(